# php display data from database with char search

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display a record from a mysql database depending on the char posted from a form input. But I can't get this to work.
My HTLM code is below

```
<form action='headcode_Db_connect.php' method='POST'>
<input type="text" name="headcode" value="" maxlength="2">
</form>
```

My PHP code

```
<?php
$headcode = $_POST['headcode'];
echo $headcode;

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password="789852"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="work"; // Database name 
$tbl_name = "headcodes";

// Connect to server and select database.
$link = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


//Retrieve all data from the table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE LIKE '%$headcode%'";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql, $link);
// if successfully, displays message "Successful". 
if($result1){
    $connect = "connected";
    echo "Successful";
    echo "<BR>";
}
else {
    echo "ERROR";
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
    $number = $row['number'];
}
echo $number;
?>
```

I keep getting an error. The data being sent will be 1A or 2A and should display the number from the database for this record. If I change `WHERE LIKE '%$headcode%'";` to `WHERE headcode = '1A'";` I get a result of 17 which is correct. So how can I use the POST variable to give this result.

Comment: You say: "I keep getting an error.". It would be helpful if you mention the exact error you get. Anyway, your `WHERE LIKE '%$headcode%'"` is missing something, namely `headcode =`. So it should be `WHERE headcode = '$headcode'"`. I leave out the obligatory warning against SQL-injection.

Comment: Thanks I have changed it to 'headcode = ' which has now given a success return but still not given the number in the row.

Comment: The obvious question is: Does your table have a column named 'number'? To check that put this in your fetch loop: `print_r($row);echo '<br>';`. You do know not to use any of these mysql functions for a production environment? They are deprecated.

Comment: Yes it does have number column. If I replace `headcode = '$headcode'"` with `headcode = '1A'` I get the result number 17 displayed on the screen so the rest of the code works but when using the variable it does not. i am not using this on production only for my own learning interest

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE LIKE '%$headcode%'"
```

If you searched for `at` (for example), the following would all match:

```
at, bat, cat, rat
```

However , if you lose the first `%`, It must **start** with your search term letters

```
WHERE LIKE '$headcode%'"
```

which would return all words beginning with `at`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the below code.

```
<?php
$headcode = $_POST['headcode'];

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password="789852"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="work"; // Database name 
$tbl_name = "headcodes";

// Connect to server and select database.
$link = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


//Retrieve all data from the table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE headcode = '$headcode'";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql, $link);

if($result1){
    echo "Successful";
    echo "<BR>";
}
else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
    $number = $row['number'];
}
echo $number;
?>
```